# ParallelForeach<T> activity in workflow designed via visio

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

In sharepoint online and workflow engine V4, there is possibility to create parallel foreach cycle in visual studio.

Since there is option to edit XAML definition of workflow via combination of sharepoint designer and Visio, is there a way how to use parallel foreach in Visio? There is no such diagram element available, but it does not make sence to me why it would not be possible. Maybe some workarround?